# Is lion upgrade compatible with parallels 6?

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

I just upgraded my one month old osx desktop computer to lion. I had parallels desktop 6 on it and now I cannot access parallels. Do I have to reload windows? Have I lost everything in windows?
I must have to it for  my business. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You should contact the technical support at the Parallels company.

They state that you must update to Parallels Desktop for Mac build 6.0.12094 for compatibility with Lion, and they list more information at [this link](http://www.parallels.com/support/pdfm6/).

Here are [support documents from Parallels](http://kb.parallels.com/?q=lion&qprod=1345&qcat=any&qlang=en&qLangEn=0&displayNumber=10&qOp=AND) concerning Lion compatibility.